# Objective-C - perform a function at given time/date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datetime, selector, delayed-execution

How might one get a function to be called at given time and date?  For example, I would like to store some values of some variables at midnight (and clear them to zero) so they can be compared with the previous days values.

How might I accomplish this in Objective-C?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Will your app be running at midnight? The only reliable option is to have a server running on Microsoft Azure or something, which will execute the task at midnight. You can't assume your app will be launched at midnight on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got quite a few options, depending on what you're after.

The obvious place to start is [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

There's also the [performSelector withDelay function family](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Lastly, a cool extension I sometimes use, [delayed blocks](http://forrst.com/posts/Delayed_Blocks_in_Objective_C-0Fn).

Oh, one more - you can also setup [Local Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use NSTimer's `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` to set the time you want a method to be run.